# How to execute a command inside a singularity container that do not interact/sources options from the host OS?

Tags: containers, singularity-container

I have a binary installed on a Docker container that I have been trying to run via Singularity:

```
singularity run docker://repo/container_image ./repository/bin --flag
```

The problem is that with such command it sources my `.bashrc`, which is causing some problems with the binary.
So I tried running it with `--no-home` and flaged repositories to be mounted with `-B`:

```
singularity run --no-home -B /hostrepo01:/data,/hostrepo02:/results docker://repo/container_image ./repository/bin --flag
```

This still imports some paths form my host os, for instance if I open a Singularity shell with the options bellow and do a `cd`, the shell tries to access the adress I have for my `home` on the host OS.

```
singularity run --no-home -B /hostrepo01:/data,/hostrepo02:/results docker://repo/container_image
```

How can I execute a command inside a singularity container that do not interact/sources options from the host OS, other than what I specify with the `-B` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--contain` flag

```
  -c, --contain                use minimal /dev and empty other
                               directories (e.g. /tmp and $HOME) instead
                               of sharing filesystems from your host
```

```
singularity run --contain -B /hostrepo01:/data,/hostrepo02:/results docker://repo/container_image
```